# How to install from backports?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center, backport

I come from debian. Fresh installation of Ubuntu.

backports is in sources.list after fresh install.

```
root@Gold:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep back
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Official documention is exactly how'd id expect, same as debian. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

Doesnt work. Apt not seeing it.

```
root@Gold:~# apt install -t 
kinetic          kinetic-updates  now              
root@Gold:~# apt install -t kinetic-backports htop
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'kinetic-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Simply put, how do i install packages from backports?

```
root@Gold:~# lsb_release -cs
kinetic
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, it can matter?

Comment: Your paste seems to indicate you're using *kinetic* or 22.10; ie. a release that is the latest (*only a few days old*) and a release that doesn't match the page you actually provided, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports and "*newer versions of software for older Ubuntu releases.*"  ie. you're not using an "***older***" Ubuntu release, but the very latest where most backports come from.

Comment: FYI:  If you were hoping to get backports from Ubuntu *ll*, work on that hasn't yet commenced (*last time I checked a couple of hours ago, why I'm having to call it ll, as I don't yet know its codename*)

Comment: Completely overlooked and unaware that this was released just 2 short days ago. I would assume this explains why backports does not exist yet. Seems like things are correct, just the repo doesnt exist if i follow currently, but will in the future with time.

Comment: If you want to post as an answer, i can accept, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.10 (*kinetic kudu*) is only a few days old. A [release annoucement](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/10/20/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-released/) gives the date of the official Mailing List post as

> Originally posted to the ubuntu-announce mailing list on **Thu Oct 20**
> 19:13:20 UTC 2022 by Łukasz ‘sil2100’ Zemczak, on behalf of the Ubuntu
> Release Team

The [backports document (wiki page) you provided](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) tells you

> "newer versions of software **for older Ubuntu releases**."

alas currently you're on the newest release, and development on the *ll* release hasn't started.

Note:  I have to call it *ll* as its still so early, I don't yet know the codename. It's still Saturday night (AEST) my local time zone, and I didn't learn the codename of *kinetic* until Sunday if I recall correctly last cycle.

(*I just did a quick scan for the bug report that will cause the setup of the new repository but I didn't see it. Yes in most cycles I usually know the codename this many hours post-release, but as per last cycle; it's not the first time I don't; ie. you're too early with nothing even possible to be backported yet*)

Comment: my example of Sunday for *kinetic* maybe incorrect (*it's from memory & I don't intend looking up logs to see the exact day/time*); that cycle was much slower than average and it may have happened early Monday.. but either way I'm pretty sure I didn't know what *kk* was six months ago, just like I don't know what *ll* is... The codename needs to be known in order to create bug report & set the process in motion to create repository etc.